# How to calculate day specific data from accumulated data

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle table with values for two accounts and each record will have Date field. First day of the week will have only data relevant to the Day 1 but when we see the data for Day2 in a week it has accumulated data. So we need to subtract Day2 data from previous day data to calculate exact data for Day2.Similar approach for Day3..Day7.

Please suggest the best approach in SQL query to handle this requirement. I am very sorry to bother you. I am totally new to SQL.Really appreciate your valuable inputs.As an example, there are 6 columns with header are given below

```
Center          Entity      Bonus   Year    Period      Incentive
MANUFACTURING   NEW YORK    1200    FY18    31-12-2017  120
MANUFACTURING   NEW YORK    1500    FY18    01-01-2018  250
MANUFACTURING   NEW YORK    1800    FY18    01-01-2018  320
```

So assuming Dec 31, 2017 is the first day of the week, the data record will show only data for that day 1. When we move on to Day 2 of the week i.e. Jan 01, 2018, it has accumulated data which includes Day 1 and day2. So we need to subtract Day2 data from Day1 data to calculate exact data for data 2. 1500 - 1200 = 300 is the exact value for Day 2. Similar approach we need to follow for Day3, day4, Day5,Day6 and Day7.

Expected output is given below

```
Center          Entity     Bonus Year    Period   Incentive
MANUFACTURING   NEW YORK    1200 FY18   01-01-2018     120
MANUFACTURING   NEW YORK    300  FY18   01-01-2018     130
MANUFACTURING   NEW YORK    300  FY18   01-01-2018     70
```

[image]

Comment: It's not bother, but please include some sample data, ideally in tabular form, so that we may see the actual problem.   Your description alone is a bit vague.

Comment: Center Entity Bonus Year Period Incentive
MANUFACTURING NEW YORK 1200 FY18 01-01-2018 120
MANUFACTURING NEW YORK 1500 FY18 01-01-2018 250
MANUFACTURING NEW YORK 1800 FY18 01-01-2018 320

Comment: Hi Tim,I just posted the raw data for your reference. Thanks for your kind 
 attention.

Comment: Add this data to the question.  I tried doing so from your comment, but it didn't make any sense.

Comment: i have uploaded the data file image

Comment: Please don't attach pictures for data. Edit your question (I.e. not comment) with sample data and expected results.

Comment: Please show us the expected output. We're getting closer now.

Comment: Hi Tim,I just pasted the expected output for your reference.Thanks for your kind help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple `LAG()` function with `NVL()`.

```
select Center, Entity, Bonus,Year,Period,
Incentive - NVL( LAG(Incentive , 1) OVER ( ORDER BY Period ), 0) Incentive
FROM yourtable;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/94c77/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a self join with you table on period and do the subtraction from previous date's data.

looks like you have typo in the test data and result, the dates should be incremental as stated in description, but it has duplicate.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8c5428/8)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (Center varchar2(13), Entity varchar2(8), Bonus int, Year varchar2(4), Period DATE, Incentive int)
;

INSERT INTO t (Center, Entity, Bonus, Year, Period, Incentive)
         VALUES ('MANUFACTURING', 'NEW YORK', 1200, 'FY18', DATE '2017-12-31', 120);
INSERT INTO t (Center, Entity, Bonus, Year, Period, Incentive)
         VALUES ('MANUFACTURING', 'NEW YORK', 1500, 'FY18', DATE '2018-01-01', 250);
INSERT INTO t (Center, Entity, Bonus, Year, Period, Incentive)
         VALUES ('MANUFACTURING', 'NEW YORK', 1800, 'FY18', DATE '2018-01-02', 320);
;
```

**Query**:

```
select t1.center, 
  t1.entity, 
  t1.bonus - nvl (t2.bonus,0) bonus, 
  t1.year, 
  t1.period, 
  t1.incentive - nvl(t2.incentive,0) incentive 
from t t1 
left outer join t t2
on t1.period = t2.period + 1
order by t1.period
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8c5428/8/0)**:

```
|        CENTER |   ENTITY | BONUS | YEAR |               PERIOD | INCENTIVE |
|---------------|----------|-------|------|----------------------|-----------|
| MANUFACTURING | NEW YORK |  1200 | FY18 | 2017-12-31T00:00:00Z |       120 |
| MANUFACTURING | NEW YORK |   300 | FY18 | 2018-01-01T00:00:00Z |       130 |
| MANUFACTURING | NEW YORK |   300 | FY18 | 2018-01-02T00:00:00Z |        70 |
```